# Django number_format not function

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the intcomma to format my number in template, but it cannot work properly.

```
{%load humanize%}
{%blocktrans with val=myvalue|intcomma%}The number is {{val}}{%endblocktrans%}
```

After some searching, I found the django.utils.formats.number_format is not function. Hereunder is my testing:

```
corpweb@56944bf480d1:~$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.4.4 (default, Feb 17 2016, 02:50:56) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import locale
>>> from django.utils.formats import number_format
>>> val=123456789
>>> number_format(val,force_grouping=True)
'123456789'
>>> locale.getlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>>
```

Is there have anything I setup wrong?

Comment: have you tried `{{val|intcomma}}`?

Comment: Do you have `USE_L10N = True` in your `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering templates or using `number_format` outside of the Django app flow the translation module is not activated. [Here are a few notes and instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) on how to turn on translation in custom management commands.

To make the shell example work we just need to activate the translation module as such:

```
(venv) $ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar  1 2018, 18:36:50)
>>> from django.utils.formats import number_format
>>> from django.utils import translation
>>> translation.activate('en-us')
>>> number_format(50000, force_grouping=True)
'50,000'
```

The key line above is: `translation.activate('en-us')`

Comment: you save my life:

`translation.activate('en-us')`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok with your setup I guess. Just set `USE_L10N = True` in your `settings.py` if it is set to False, as @Tim Schneider mentioned, and you better try it like this `{{ val|intcomma }}` as @Leonard2 mentioned and it must work. And also as it is mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/humanize/) make sure:

> To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.